# "rails server" on existing working application not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm happily configuring my new laptop to work on my already existing projects. 
I copied the folder of an application and all its subfolders, and now have it in the new laptop.
It seems I cannot start the server by typing `rails server` command at the root of the project.
I tried to create a new project and start it and it works just fine, so I really have no idea of what to do. Rails versions are the same and identical `Gemfile`.
This is the result of the `rails server` command:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                             # Default: /home/toni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem   path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
  [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
ETC...
```

thanks!

Comment: Did you run the bundle command?

Comment: Yes, I did run the `bundle install` and also ( after changing to the version I need) a `bundle update`

Comment: What if you try `./bin/rails server`? or `bundle exec rails server`?

Comment: Also, what does this command return? `type rvm | head -n 1`?

Comment: OK... one more lol. Does `rails -v` return the Rails version you expect?

Comment: @kstevens715:many questions! cool. Well there is no `bin` folder in the root path. However if I do `~/.rvm/gems/ruby1.9.3-p364/bin/rails server` I get the same results. Also `bundle exec rails server` outputs the same result. The command `type rvm | head -n 1` outputs: `rvm is a function`. Aaaand `rails -v` indeed outputs `Rails 3.2.11`, which is the expected one and the one found in the `Gemfile`. thanks!

Comment: @Ganesh kunwar: There is actually "no error" per se. It's just that running `rails server` from the root outputs me some sort of `manual` of how to use rails binary, instead of just starting the server.

Comment: Does 'whereis rails' also return '~/.rvm/gems/ruby1.9.3-p364/bin/rails'?

Comment: @kstevens715: actually `whereis rails` outputs `rails:  `. However if I `$which rails` the result is the expecte one `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/rails`.  this is weird!

Comment: You haven't made any changes to the project since it was copied from the other computer? Is it the same version of rails and ruby, etc.?

Comment: There is an option you can pass 'rails new' to ignore files that already exist. Not at a computer so not sure what it is. You could try running that over your existing project to replace any missing files. Not sure if it'll work but might be worth a try.

Comment: I'd also try creating a project specific gemset and rerunning bundler. It's a good idea anyway. Use this link to create a project .rvmrc file. https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/

Comment: One more... I just noticed you said you did a bundle update? What were you updating? Did you try rails server before the update?

Comment: @kstevens715: I was `bundle update` since I changed rails from `3.2.9` to `3.2.11`. Also `rails server` was not working before the `update`.I found a workaround thanks to you, which is the `rails new` skipping existing files.I tried to use the `--skip` option when `rails new`-ing, however I didnt figure it out that well.I just created a new project, and copied the `Gemfile`, `app/`, and `db/` files. works! Tho not all functionality is there(thinking this dropbox's fault). Im afraid `script/rails` was missing, since it's present in the working root but not the other one.Really THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem. I forgot about script/rails, but I promoted the comment that resolved the issue to an actual answer if you want to accept it. BTW, if you haven't tried it I would recommend you look into hosting your code on github. You can then clone your repo to different computers and it might avoid this situation.

Comment: yep! this is the only project I didnt host there.thanks, answer accepted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rails 3.x, this will occur when `script/rails` is missing. The file could accidentally have been deleted or it may have never been committed to source control if you've just cloned the project to another machine. You'll need to find or regenerate it.

Rails determines if it's actually "in" a Rails project by checking if `script/rails` exists. If it doesn't find that file, it assumes it's not a Rails project:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.21/railties/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb#L21-L23

There is an option you can pass 'rails new' to ignore files that already exist:

```
rails new APPNAME -s
```

You could try running that over your existing project to replace any missing files.

See also:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/initialization.html

Comment: This seems like a very overlooked problem in Rails, considering how easy it is to stumble upon... I cloned an app of mine that was working fine, and ran `bundle install`, and had this problem. Thanks for the tip; it worked and I was able to learn more about how Rails works as a result.

Comment: No problem, @SteveBenner. I just dug into the problem a little more out of curiosity and found some more details about why it occurs. I've edited my answer accordingly, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the output of the rails command it seems that you do not execute the command 'rails server' in the root directory of a rails project.

You should check if you are in the correct directory and if all files have been copied.

Comment: I am certainly at the root directory of the project. Where the `Gemfile` is!